# Application of Brouwer's theorem in Conceptual Mathematics: A first introduction to categories

Tags: category-theory

For the 2nd ed. of Lawvere and Schanuel's Conceptual Mathematics: A first introduction to categories, on p. 132 we are given the following scenario (reproduced for those who don't have the book):

Consider 2 cars traveling on a highway from Buffalo to Rochester:

```
---------*--------------------*----------
       Buffalo             Rochester
```

Person A drives starting from Buffalo and ending in Rochester. Person B starts and finishes at the same time, starting and finishing anywhere between Buffalo and Rochester. During the drive both are allowed to go anywhere along the highway they want, even west of Buffalo or east of Rochester. Will Person A and Person B meet at some point?

There are 3 objects involved: `I`, an interval, `E`, its endpoints, and `R`, the long road. This gives two inclusion maps `i` and `j`:

```
        *                   *        E
        |                   |
        |                   | j
        V                   V
        *-------------------*        I
        |   |   |   |   |   |
        |   |   |   |   |   | i
        V   V   V   V   V   V  
------------------------------------ R
```

Person A's travel gives an additional map $m: I \rightarrow R$ and person B's gives another $y: I \rightarrow R$.

Express the restrictions given above on Person A and B's travels by equations involving composition of maps, introducing other objects and maps as needed. Then formulate the conclusion that at some time Person A and B meet in terms of composition of maps (You will need to introduce the object $1$).

This exercise is in the section describing Brouwer's retraction and fixed point theorems. My initial thoughts are:

1. Some restriction involving $m = i \circ j$ to indicate $m$ must start at Buffalo and end at Rochester.
2. Some map $f: 1 \rightarrow I$ where $m \circ f = y \circ f$, where $f$ indicates the point at which they meet ?

I am not too sure how to put this in more formal terms, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Consider objects End points $(E)$ of Interval $(I)$, $I$ and $R$ in some category $\mathscr C$, where every map is a continuous map. Following is one way, in which you can describe the situation.

- Inclusion map $j:E\rightarrow I$. Which basically are the ends of road $BR$ (Road from Buffalo to Rochester).
- Inclusion map $i:I\rightarrow R$. Which says that object $I$ is also contained in object $R$.

Suppose maps $y, m:I\rightarrow R$ describe two travels. Then following are the restrictions on the travel:

- $y\circ j = i\circ j$. This restriction means that, $y$ travel has end points same as end points of road $BR$.
- $\exists o:E\rightarrow I \ such \ that \ i\circ o = m\circ j$. We know that $m\circ j$ describe the end points of travel $m$, and these points lie on the road $BR$. Also, $BR$ road is described by map $i$. Therefore, there exists some family of points $o:E\rightarrow I$ which are mapped to family of points $m\circ j$ by $i$.